# Here is the link for apex class ActivityController

Tags: salesforce, apex

It is apex class for the question which is related to [Auto Refresh for Lignting Component After data change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76303207/auto-refresh-for-lignting-component-after-data-change).
I added that link page there are included other component code and javascript code to review.

**I would like to know auto refresh after the data is changed and clicked the finish button.**
Here is the code for this:

ActivityController.apxc

```
public with sharing class ActivityController {
    public ActivityController() {
    }
public class ActivityData implements Comparable {
    @AuraEnabled public String RecordId {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String WhatId {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String WhoId {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String Type {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String Subtype {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String ContactId {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String Subject {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String Description {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public Date ActivityDate {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String ActivityType {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String Status {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public Boolean IsClosed {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public Boolean IsOverdue {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public Decimal TotalCallTime {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String UserJourney {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public Date CompletedDate {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String WhatName {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String WhoName {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String ContactName {get; set;}
    
    public ActivityData (String recordId, String type, String subtype, String WhatId, String WhoId, String contactId,
                             String subject, String description, String status, Date activityDate, Boolean isClosed, String activityType,
                             Decimal totalCallTime,String userJourney, DateTime completedDateTime,
                             String whatName, String whoName, String contactName) {
                                 this.RecordId = recordId;
                                 this.Type = type;
                                 this.Subtype = subtype;
                                 this.WhatId = whatId;
                                 this.WhoId = whoId;
                                 this.ContactId = contactId;
                                 this.Subject = subject;
                                 this.Description = description;
                                 this.Status = status;
                                 this.ActivityDate = activityDate;
                                 this.ActivityType = activityType;
                                 this.IsClosed = isClosed;
                                 this.IsOverdue = ((activityDate != null) && activityDate < Date.today());
                                 this.TotalCallTime = totalCallTime;
                                 this.UserJourney = userJourney;
                                 this.CompletedDate = (completedDateTime==null)?null:completedDateTime.date();
                                 this.WhatName = whatName;
                                 this.WhoName = whoName;
                                 this.ContactName = contactName;
                             }
  
    
    public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        Integer compareResult = 1;
        if (compareTo == null) {return compareResult;}
        
        ActivityData activityDataCompareTo = (ActivityData)compareTo;
        
        Date thisDate = this.ActivityDate;
        Date compareDate = activityDataCompareTo.ActivityDate;
        if (thisDate == null) {thisDate = Date.newInstance(1900, 01, 01);}
        if (compareDate == null) {compareDate = Date.newInstance(1900, 01, 01);}
        
        if (this.ActivityDate > activityDataCompareTo.ActivityDate) {compareResult = -1;}
        else {if (this.ActivityDate < activityDataCompareTo.ActivityDate) {compareResult = 1;}
              else {compareResult = 0;}}
        return compareResult;
    }   
}

@AuraEnabled
public static List<LabelValue> getTokenList (String category) {
    List<LabelValue> taskTokenList = new List<LabelValue>();
    try {
        List<String> tokenList;
        tokenList= new List<String>(Token.GetOrderedTokens(category).keySet());
        for (String tokenLabel : tokenList) {
            LabelValue newOption;
            newOption= new LabelValue(tokenLabel, tokenLabel, tokenLabel);
            taskTokenList.add(newOption);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        system.debug(ex.getMessage());
        throw new AuraHandledException('List Task Tokens failed' + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return taskTokenList;      
}

@AuraEnabled
public static void setTaskStatus (Id taskId, String taskStatus) { 
    try {
        new TaskService().setTaskStatus(taskId, taskStatus);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        system.debug(ex.getMessage());
        throw new AuraHandledException('Update Task Status failed' + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@AuraEnabled
public static Id getParticipantId(Id taskId) {
    Id participantId;
    try {
        participantId = new TaskService().getParticipantId(taskId);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        system.debug(ex.getMessage());
        throw new AuraHandledException('Get ParticipantId failed' + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return participantId;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static List<ActivityData> getCallList(Id recordId) {
    List<ActivityData> activityList;
    activityList= new List<ActivityData>();
    List<Task> tasks;
    tasks= new TaskService().getCallHistory(recordId);
    for (Task task : tasks) {
        ActivityData activityData = new ActivityData(task.Id, task.Type, task.TaskSubType, task.WhatId, task.WhoId, task.Contact__c, 
                                                             task.Subject, task.Description, task.Status, task.ActivityDate, task.IsClosed, 'Task',task.Call_Duration__c,task.User_Journey__c,
                                                             task.CompletedDateTime, task.What.Name, task.Who.Name, task.Contact__r.Name);
        if (task.IsClosed) {activityData.ActivityDate = task.CompletedDateTime.date();}
        activityList.add(activityData);
    }
  
    return activityList;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static List<ActivityData> getEventList(Id recordId) {
    List<ActivityData> activityList;
    activityList= new List<ActivityData>();
    List<Event> events;
    events= new EventService().getEventList(recordId);
    for (Event event : events) {
        ActivityData activityData = new ActivityData(
            event.Id, event.Type, event.EventSubType, event.WhatId, event.WhoId, event.Contact__c, 
            event.Subject, event.Description, 'Complete', event.ActivityDate, true, 'Event', 0, '',
            event.ActivityDate, event.What.Name, event.Who.Name, event.Contact__r.Name);
        activityList.add(activityData);
    }
    return activityList;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static List<ActivityData> getActivityList(Id recordId, Boolean includeEvents) {
    List<ActivityData> activityList;
    activityList= new List<ActivityData>();
   
        system.debug(recordId);
        activityList.addAll(ActivityController.getCallList(recordId));
        if (includeEvents) {
            activityList.addAll(ActivityController.getEventList(recordId));
        }
        activityList.sort();
    return activityList;
}

  @AuraEnabled
public static List<ActivityData> getActivityListforTesting(Id recordId, Boolean includeEvents) {
    List<ActivityData> activityList;
    activityList= new List<ActivityData>();
   
        system.debug(recordId);
        activityList.addAll(ActivityController.getCallList(recordId));
        if (includeEvents) {
            activityList.addAll(ActivityController.getEventList(recordId));
        }
        activityList.sort();
    return activityList;
    }


}
```